# Using JsonCpp on X-Cross platform library

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, jsoncpp

I'm making a library in C++ with OpenCV and JsonCpp towards building a library for Android and iOS.

On testing my library for Android, I'm making the JNI files but when I try to load the library I'm getting

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol
>   "_ZN4Json6WriterD2Ev" referenced by "libXYZ.so"...

and that's because I think I'm not building my Json library very well.

The library that I use is this one: https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp

My Android.mk is:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/jsoncpp/Android.mk
include /Users/localmac/Desktop/AndroidDevelopment/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/localmac/mylibrary/OpenCVtry/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/localmac/Desktop/RD/OpenCVtry/Libraries/jsoncpp-master/include

LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true
LOCAL_MODULE    := libXYZ
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := androidClass.cpp main.cpp utils.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I have no idea of how to do this.

Thank you in advance.

---

**EDIT** it's not the NDK Compiling's fault.

Even if I compile the JsonCpp, I get the

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN4Json6WriterD2Ev" referenced by "libXYZ.so"...

**EDIT** My jsoncpp/Android.mk :

> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>
> LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp LOCAL_MODULE := libJsoncpp
>
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/jsoncpp/include
>
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/lib_json/json_reader.cpp \
>                    src/lib_json/json_value.cpp \
>                      src/lib_json/json_writer.cpp
>
> include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: I don't see where do you link with the jsoncpp lib in your makefile.

Comment: sorry, I added after... I'm editing it

Comment: And what's the content of your jsoncpp's `android.mk` ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not linking against Jsoncpp in your makefile. You should add the following line:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libJsoncpp
```

before the last `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`.

You must specify module names for this variable (and its sister `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES`), that is, what you specified for the `LOCAL_MODULE` variable.

Also, that spares you from specifiying the includes in the `LOCAL_C_INCLUDE` variable (as the makefile will include them directly when specifying the library in the variable I mentioned at the top of my post).

**EDIT:** For the sake of completeness, I'll add that you can specify multiple libraries like that:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES = libJsoncpp \
                         libOpenCV \
                         ...
```

and the same goes for `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES`.

Comment: You are right... but instead I'm getting a "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN2cv3Mat8copySizeERKS0_" referenced by "libXYZ.so"..." and it seems that it's like a cv::Mat.copy(Size())... is it the same problem ? (thank you very much)

Comment: Well... Where do you link with OpenCV? :D (Hint: I don't see it in the makefile you posted)

Comment: Oh thanks again: `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libJsoncpp libopencv_java` I think I will have to add some more :)

Comment: I am building same jsoncpp source code I am getting following error , checked so many threads on SO not getting proper solution. Please check the error and suggest.Android NDK: jni/jsnlib/Android.mk:jsnlib: LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME should not include file extensions
Android NDK: jni/jsnlib/Android.mk:jsnlib: LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME must not contain a file extension