# ndk-build for jsoncpp always giving one error

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, jsoncpp

Pre-requisites : I am using Android Studio 2.1.2

I have downloaded source of jsoncpp from following link

https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp

I have already checked following SO thread , not getting proper solutions :

[LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME should not include file extensions i get this error each time i run ndk-build in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322162/local-module-filename-should-not-include-file-extensions-i-get-this-error-each-t)

[Using JsonCpp on X-Cross platform library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061564/using-jsoncpp-on-x-cross-platform-library)

My common Android.mk is as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

#JsonCpp lib

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := jsoncpplib

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/jsnlib/Android.mk

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := jsnlib

LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

With code for building some other libraries too , which is working fine.

My jsoncpp's Android.mk is as follows

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/jsnlib/include/json/*.h

FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/jsnlib/src/lib_json/*.cpp)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

LOCAL_MODULE := jsnlib
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME:= libjsnlib

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

When I do ndk-build always getting following error

```
Android NDK: jni/jsnlib/Android.mk:jsnlib: LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME should not include file extensions
Android NDK: jni/jsnlib/Android.mk:jsnlib: LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME must not contain a file extension
```

Comment: Why do you need `LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME` at all in this case? Seems like you could just remove it.

Comment: @Michael Tried removing that also, no change , getting same error. One more thing tried with LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/jsnlib/include/json also, no success.

Comment: Well, you should probably move that `include $(LOCAL_PATH)/jsnlib/Android.mk
` in your main Android.mk so that it's above `include $(CLEAR_VARS)`.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the input. Now I am able to build .so for jsoncpp. Only problem is when I shift this inlcuding for make file above its giving problem while building so's the cpp files I am including above it. This is another issue , I may need to declare separate var for local path then it will get fixed. That's what I think.Can you please put your input in answer? so that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that while you're in the middle of defining your `jsoncpplib` module you include another makefile, which contains its own module definition:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := jsoncpplib
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/jsnlib/Android.mk
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := jsnlib
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

You should move the inclusion of the other makefile to above the where you're doing `CLEAR_VARS`:

```
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/jsnlib/Android.mk

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := jsoncpplib
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := jsnlib
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

---

Also, `LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME:= libjsnlib` seems redundant, since `LOCAL_MODULE := jsnlib` should result in the same library name.